# How to parse my command arguments into bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i got something like this

```
./foo.sh --textfile foo1.txt < foo2.txt
```

how can i parse foo1.txt and foo2.txt into my bash script

its not that safe to use $1 and $2 etc, because user may use different argument sequence to run this program

for example:

```
./foo.sh < foo2.txt --textfile foo1.txt
```

Comment: The `< foo2.txt` is a command to the shell (telling it to connect `foo2.txt` to your program's stdin before your program is started), not to your program. It's not available for your program to read.

Comment: 1. You can't get foo2.txt, read up on redirection. 2. The two lines do completely different things.

Comment: Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 for a best-practices mechanism for argument parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As some commenters have noted, you can't get at `foo2.txt`

To answer your question more generally, though, you should use a construct like this to parse your command line args:

```
while [ "${#}" -gt 0 ] ; do
    case "${1}" in
    # Do some processing on the args you're expecting
    # Maybe create some local variables and fill them as you go
    esac
    shift
done
```